# Уменьшить стороны индекса массива как воронку

Tags: java

Нужно сделать такую воронку из красных чисел.

[image]

Вот что я сейчас имею

```
public class Matrix {
    public static void main(String[] args) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int [][] twoDim = {
            { 1,2,3,4,5 },
            { 5,4,3,2,1 },
            { 6,7,8,9,1 },
            { 2,4,3,1,3 },
            { 5,4,3,2,1 },
        };

        int max = twoDim[0][0];

        for(int i = 0; i < twoDim.length; i++) { // 1 2 3 4 5
            for(int j = 0; j <twoDim[i].length; j++) { // 1 2 3 4 5

                if(twoDim[i][j]>max) {
                    max = twoDim[i][j];
                }

            } // end of for J

        // System.out.println();

        } // end of for i

        System.out.println(max);
    }
}
```

Я только нашел максимум из массива, но не могу понять как автоматизировано сделать воронку, чтобы индекс уменьшался на 1 с обеих сторон

Comment: Что значит - сделать воронку? Раскрасить их надо или что

Comment: Нет, нужно каждую j индекс уменьшать i индекс с обоих сторон как на картинке

Comment: Т.е. надо найти максимальное число из этих красных чисел?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Но сработает только на квадратных матрицах.
Алгоритм перебора такой: сначала уменьшаем по одному элементу с боков, а как перейдем середину, то начинаем увеличивать

```
int [][] twoDim = {
    { 1,2,3,4,5 },
    { 5,4,3,2,1 },
    { 6,7,8,9,1 },
    { 2,4,3,1,3 },
    { 5,4,3,2,1 }
};

int max = 0;

int wrap = 0;
boolean flag = false;

for(int i = 0; i < twoDim.length; i++) {

    for(int j = wrap; j < twoDim[i].length - wrap; j++) {
        if(twoDim[i][j] > max) {
            max = twoDim[i][j];
        }
    }

    if(flag) { wrap--; } else { wrap++; }
    if(wrap == twoDim[0].length/2) { flag = true; }
}
```